# What function should I use in Excel for searching multiple cells for a reoccurring words?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example:

> baby
>   house
>   empty
>   people
>   people
>   pram
>   pram
>   pram

should return:

> 1
>   1
>   1
>   1
>   0
>   1
>   0
>   0

so pretty much it should only return 1 if the word is a novel word compared to the rest of the previous list. Or in other words the function should produce 0 if it is a duplicate of any words in the list above it.

I've tried `=IF(FIND(A5, A1:A4), 0, 1)`, but that only returns `#VALUE!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the data starting in row 1, you can use

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)>1,0,1)
```

Copy down.

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly however it counts blank space as 1 all the time is there away to automatically count an empty cell as 0?

Comment: Fixed it my self, kinda of a roun about way of doing it but whatever. I just created a new colum with


 =IF(ISBLANK(C2), "empty", C2)


so it only counts empty once and all other empty cells are give 0. 
Thank you for your help, saved me hours of counting spreadsheets one  by one!